# Merge multiple csv files into one using js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, d3.js

Due to the timeout issues, I have converted the download to ajax short calls, and part downloads. Now I need those part CSV files to merge into one using js or jquery.

The code is given below.

```
$(document).on('click', '#downloadCaratReportAjax', function () {
    var statusId = 1;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/admin-reports/carat/download-report',
        type: 'POST',
        beforeSend: function () {
                $('#spiner-load-please-wait').modal({
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    keyboard: false
                });
        },
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        data: {
                    statusId: statusId
                },
        success: function (res) {
                var csvFile = new Blob([res]);
                var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
                var blob = new Blob(["\ufeff", csvFile]);
                var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                downloadLink.href = url;
                downloadLink.download = "draft-campaigns-cost.csv";

                document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
                downloadLink.click();
                document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
        },
        error: function (res) {

        },
    }).promise().done(function () {
        var statusId = 2;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/admin-reports/carat/download-report',
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function () {
                    $('#spiner-load-please-wait').modal({
                        backdrop: 'static',
                        keyboard: false
                    });
            },
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            data: {
                        statusId: statusId
                    },
            success: function (res) {
                    var csvFile = new Blob([res]);
                    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
                    var blob = new Blob(["\ufeff", csvFile]);
                    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    downloadLink.href = url;
                    downloadLink.download = "approved-campaign-cost.csv";

                    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
                    downloadLink.click();
                    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
            },
            error: function (res) {

            },
        })
    }).promise().done(function () {
```

and upto four promises for individual csvs. Now i need all these csv files into one. I have searched all over the internet and found nothing. Please help.